# Destiny's Notorious VoG Spirit Bloom Chest

Tags: destiny

In Destiny's Vault of Glass raid, once the Templar boss is defeated, a chest spawns by an alternative tunnel route in the raid. The chest will commonly contain glimmer and spirit bloom, giving it the name the "spirit bloom chest". There is a very prevalent suspicion among players that opening the spirit bloom chest will decrease the chances of getting an exotic item from the exotic chest by the Gorgon's Labyrinth. Most players will ignore the spirit bloom chest whether or not they believe the rumor, because the chest isn't really worth opening anyway. However, a member of our raid this week got a legendary engram from the spirit bloom chest.

*Does opening the spirit bloom chest really affect exotic chances*, or have we all been missing out on possible legendary items?

Comment: I'm voting to close this because the answers will be opinion based. Bungie has not released any set information, and so we have no concrete evidence that points one way or another.

Comment: @Thebluefish Drop chances are entirely possible to approximate (if not determinate) by a few determined individuals tirelessly grinding, or through crowd-sourced record-keeping. Sometimes in mmo type environments, even when the developers tell the players what certain rates *should* be, the player base can collect sufficient evidence to prove that despite what the rate should be, it is considerably higher/lower.

Comment: That said, it may be considerably more difficult (but not impossible) to determine if a random action (opening Chest-A) has any effect on a different action (opening Chest-B). Particularly if the desired exotics have a low drop rate. But determining if Chest-A can drop legendary items? That should be entirely plausible to confirm or deny.

Comment: I'm fairly certain there isn't a higher rate of getting a legendary engram from that chest.  You can get a legendary engram from any chest, it's just rare.  Sounds like your friend encountered a lucky coincidence.  I've also seen people open the spirit bloom chest and get exotics from the gorgon maze.  The rate is pretty low of getting an exotic, I think it'd be difficult to determine if it affected the rate.  If you're interested in chest hunting in the VoG, check out [/r/raidsecrets](http://www.reddit.com/r/raidsecrets), maybe someone can answer your question better there.

Comment: [Here](http://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/2yj3br/opening_the_spirit_bloom_chest_in_vog_does_not/) is a discussion about this topic with anecdotal evidence of people getting an exotic opening the chest.

Answer (score 1):

The internet is full of people giving anecdotal evidence of having opened the spirit bloom chest and got exotic weapons at the next one suggesting that this is no more than superstition. I'm not going to link it because it is anecdotal and is findable by google.

Given there is now no reason not to open the chest then yes, you are missing out on things by not opening a chest. The chest seems to be just like any other Venus chest generally containing a few spirit bloom and a handful of glimmer. Like all chests it also has a rare chance of something better.